# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property

Tags: jpa-2.0

I am using below jars to run jpa program but am getting an exception:

```
hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA.jar
javax.persistence.jar
```

The exception is:

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: asso_attrib_overrides.FulltimeEmployee.currentProjects.

My entity:

```java
@Entity
public class FulltimeEmployee extends Employee {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="EMP_PROJECTS", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="MY_EMP_ID"))
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="THE_PROJECT_ID")
    @Column(name="STARTDATE")
    protected Map<Project, Date> currentProjects;

    public Map<Project, Date> getCurrentProjects() {
        return currentProjects;
    }

      public void setCurrentProjects(Map&lt;Project, Date> currentProjects) {
        this.currentProjects = currentProjects;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According tag you are using JPA 2.0. That is not exactly true, because 3.4 is JPA 1.0 implementation. Only Hibernate versions from 3.5.x on are implementations of JPA 2.0 API.

That causes problem, because concept of using @Temporal with ElementCollection was introduced in JPA 2.0. This error is not silently ignored, because @Temporal annotation existed already in earlier version, but usage was widened in JPA 2.0 to cover your usecase. Other annotations that exist only in later specification are silently ignored and that is also likely to cause problems.

What you can do is to update Hibernate to newer version, for example to 3.6.10. If you are creating new software, there is no migration issues, so it makes sense to update directly to 4.x.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error and it turns out that i was doing

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Hope this might be helpful

Comment: This sorted me out! Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and got following when running the application.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar property: com.model.Student.currentDate
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.setType(SimpleValueBinder.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2236)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:961)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:788)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.main.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This happened as I have imported **wrong Date import statement into my class** which was

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

Remove the import statement and use following,

```
import java.util.Date;
```

Then it works.

If someone is wondering the difference between these **two imports**. Check the followings.

- java.sql.Date is a thin wrapper around millisecond value which is
  used by JDBC to identify an SQL DATE type
- java.sql.Date just represent DATE without time information while
  java.util.Date represent both Date and Time information. This is the
  major differences why java.util.Date can not directly map to
  java.sql.Date.

For more information check this out:

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/difference-between-javautildate-and.html#ixzz5KnvEjas7

Answer (score 0):

while using Date ,the return type must be Date. i.e is java.util(import java.util.Date;)

```
   private Date date;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Things Actually you have to consider.

1. use `java.util.Date`
2. make sure your fields return type is also `Date`

   ```
   @UpdateTimestamp
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private Date DATE_MODIFIED;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Correct

`@Temporal` should only be set on a `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` property

this error will get solved using  "`java.util.Date`" instead of "`java.sql.date`"

use where you created you getters and setters import it like "`import java.util.date`"

it will work...